# SQL utilizando duas tabelas

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Preciso selecionar todas os registros da tabela **solicitacoes_solicitacao** onde todos os registros da tabela **solicitacoes_tarefas** que possuem na coluna **id_solicitacao** o **id** referente à aquela solicitação, e a **dataconclusao** sejam diferente de 0000-00-00.

Seria mais ou menos o seguinte:

```
SELECT * FROM solicitacoes_solicitacao WHERE (SELECT * FROM solicitacoes_tarefas WHERE id_solicitacao = $id_da_solicitacao AND dataconclusao != 0000-00-00"
```

Já utilizo os 2 SQLs de forma separada, uma para listar as solicitações e outra para listar as tarefas de uma solicitação onde a data de conclusão é diferente de *0000-00-00*, mas preciso utilizar os dois juntos agora. Não sei se seria isso, mas dei uma pesquisada e seria a utilização de uma cláusula chamada **INNER JOIN**, dei uma lida mas não entendi bem...

Se alguém conseguir resolver meu problema agradeço!

Comment: Veja este artigo, irá esclarecer : https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-join-entenda-como-funciona-o-retorno-dos-dados/31006

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, fiz assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM solicitacoes_solicitacao as so WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM solicitacoes_tarefas as ta WHERE ta.dataconclusao = 0000-00-00 and ta.id_evento = 0 and ta.id_solicitacao = so.id) != 0";
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim.

```
SELECT * FROM solicitacoes_solicitacao ss
LEFT JOIN solicitacoes_tarefas st ON st.id_solicitacao = ss.id

WHERE ss.dataconclusao != '0000-00-00' 
AND ss.dataconclusao IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   solicitacoes_solicitacao ss, 
       solicitacoes_tarefas sf 
WHERE  ss.id_solicitacao = 'vlr da solicitacao' 
       AND sf.dataconclusao != 0000 - 00 - 00
```

Comment: Veja se resolve

Answer (score 0):

Olá.

Você pode juntar as duas tabelas, das maneiras mencionadas acima, ou utilizar o INNER JOIN, como você disse. O INNER JOIN você vai pegar os dados das duas tabelas se existir nas duas, enquanto o Left Join pega os dados da esquerda e o Right somente os dados da direita.

Lembrando que todos os Joins necessitam que os dados tenham em ambas as tabelas.

```
SELECT * FROM solicitacoes_solicitacao SS INNER JOIN solicitacoes_tarefas ST ON SS.id_solicitacao = ST.id_da_solicitacao where dataconclusao != 0000-00-00
```

Você precisa diferenciar as duas tabelas, já que os campos são iguais.

Boa sorte cara!

Answer (score -1):

Veja se é isto:

```
SELECT * FROM solicitacoes_solicitacao 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM solicitacoes_tarefas WHERE id_solicitacao = $id_da_solicitacao AND id_solicitacao = solicitacoes_solicitacao.id_solicitacao AND dataconclusao = '0000-00-00');
```

Posso ter entendido errado "todos os registros da tabela solicitacoes_tarefas". Entendi, pelo que você escreveu, que se existir algum registro de solitacoes_tarefas daquela solicitação com dataconclusao = '000-00-00' então a solicitação não deve ser considerada.